# Is there a postgres function documentation pattern that is similar in concept to javadoc?

Tags: postgresql, functions, documentation

I am mostly a Java developer. Today I am writing some postgres functions. Out of habit I keep trying to document these functions using a Javadoc-like comment style describing the function parameters and return type. Is there an official or widely supported pattern for documenting postgres functions?

Answer (score 6):

Not really, however in Postgres and many other DBMS vendors you can comment on various database objects like:

```
COMMENT ON FUNCTION my_function (timestamp) IS 'Returns Roman Numeral';
```

As far as I can tell there is no way you can comment on individual arguments for a function.

For the presentation of the documentation, you may want to have a look at:

http://schemaspy.org/

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer above, all modern Postgres versions allow named arguments for both input and output.

For example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_password(user_name_in TEXT, password_in TEXT, out password_ok boolean) ....
```

Then you can call the function with named args.

```
SELECT check_password(user_name_in := 'public', password_in := 'xyzzy');
```

I find it helps a lot to create longer but clear names for both the inputs and outputs.